# Logging local function state in serverless

Tags: serverless

I have a serverless function that handles file uploads to my S3 bucket. What I want is that everytime a file uploads I want to see logs on the handler. Is there anyway I could skip deploying everytime and see logs for my offline application state, or I can invoke local functions on file upload handlers to my S3.

Comment: what do you refer to by `offline` application?

Comment: serverless offers local invokation, which triggers lambda function written on my local files. I want handlers from my local files to be triggered when an event happens. For example: s3 file upload handlers, rekognition analysis. Otherwise, I would need to deploy my functions all over again, everytime I make changes.